# Xcode 8 Migration Tool is not working to convert Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, migration, cocoapods, xcode8

I am converting my Swift 2.3 project to 3.0 using migration tool.
This project is using cocoa pods (Alamofire, SwiftyJSON...) and working well in Xcode 8.

[image]

But when I am converting this project to Swift 3.0, I am stuck on this screen. I waited for about 3 hrs but, not luck.
Could you please help me how to successfully convert Swift 2.3 project to Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this:-

Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax

Select the files and it will show you the changes and select OK.

Comment: I already tried this. As I posted in my question, it's stuck in Generating Preview screen